# Does SWIG support "smart" C++ pointers?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, swig

I'm using a template class to handle *smart* pointers in C++. This is the template's code (simplified)

```
#ifndef __IL_REF_PTR_H__
#define __IL_REF_PTR_H__

// (More stuff here...)

// This is for DLL creation
#ifdef OPENIL_EXPORTS
#define OPENIL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define OPENIL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

namespace openil
{

    /** Smart pointer for handling referenced counted objects.*/
    template<class T> class OPENIL_API IL_ref_ptr
    {
        public:
            typedef T element_type;

            IL_ref_ptr() :m_ptr(0L) {}
            IL_ref_ptr(T* t):m_ptr(t)              { if (m_ptr) m_ptr->ref(); }
            IL_ref_ptr(const IL_ref_ptr& rp):m_ptr(rp.m_ptr)  { if (m_ptr) m_ptr->ref(); }
            ~IL_ref_ptr()                           { if (m_ptr) m_ptr->unref(); m_ptr=0; }

            inline IL_ref_ptr& operator = (const IL_ref_ptr& rp)
            {
                if (m_ptr==rp.m_ptr)
                    return *this;

                T* tmp_ptr = m_ptr;
                m_ptr       = rp.m_ptr;

                if (m_ptr)
                    m_ptr->ref();
                // unref second to prevent any deletion of any object which might
                // be referenced by the other object. i.e rp is child of the
                // original _ptr.
                if (tmp_ptr)
                    tmp_ptr->unref();

                return *this;
            }

            inline IL_ref_ptr& operator = (T* ptr)
            {
                if (m_ptr==ptr)
                    return *this;

                T* tmp_ptr = m_ptr;
                m_ptr       = ptr;

                if (m_ptr)
                    m_ptr->ref();
                // unref second to prevent any deletion of any object which might
                // be referenced by the other object. i.e rp is child of the
                // original _ptr.
                if (tmp_ptr)
                    tmp_ptr->unref();

                return *this;
            }

            // comparison operators for IL_ref_ptr.
            inline bool operator == (const IL_ref_ptr& rp) const { return (m_ptr==rp.m_ptr); }
            inline bool operator != (const IL_ref_ptr& rp) const { return (m_ptr!=rp.m_ptr); }
            inline bool operator <  (const IL_ref_ptr& rp) const { return (m_ptr<rp.m_ptr); }
            inline bool operator >  (const IL_ref_ptr& rp) const { return (m_ptr>rp.m_ptr); }

            // comparison operator for const T*.
            inline bool operator == (const T* ptr) const { return (m_ptr==ptr); }
            inline bool operator != (const T* ptr) const { return (m_ptr!=ptr); }
            inline bool operator <  (const T* ptr) const { return (m_ptr<ptr); }
            inline bool operator >  (const T* ptr) const { return (m_ptr>ptr); }


            inline       T& operator   *  ()       {return *m_ptr;}

            inline const T& operator   *  () const {return *m_ptr;}

            inline       T *operator   -> ()       {return  m_ptr;}

            inline const T *operator   -> () const {return  m_ptr;}

            inline       bool operator !  () const {return  m_ptr == 0L;}

            inline       bool valid       () const {return  m_ptr != 0L;}

            inline       T    *get        ()       {return  m_ptr;}

            inline const T    *get        () const {return  m_ptr;}

            /** take control over the object pointed to by IL_ref_ptr, unreference but do not delete even if ref count goes to 0,
            * return the pointer to the object.
            * Note, do not use this unless you are 100% sure your code handles the deletion of the object correctly, and
            * only use when absolutely required.*/
            inline T* take    () {return release();}

            inline T* release ()
            {
                T *tmp = m_ptr;

                if (m_ptr)
                    m_ptr->unref_nodelete();

                m_ptr = 0;

                return tmp;
            }

        private:
            T* m_ptr;
    };
}

#endif
```

This template is part of a complex C++ DLL, and I need to use it in Java, Python, PHP and Ruby projects. So, I'm trying to create a wrapper using SWIG 3. But reading the [documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html), I find this:

> The following C++ features are not currently supported: Overloaded
>   versions of certain operators (new, delete, etc.)

As I'm basically overloading a few operators in my template, will I have problems with SWIG? I never used it before, so I guess it will require a considerable amount of time until I get results. I don't want to walk all the road and then find that it's useless for my purpose (again: use my library from Java, Python PHP and Ruby).

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477451/swig-java-c-smart-pointers-inclusion) similar question, but has no answer yet.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: There is support, but outside of boost/std namespace shared pointers it's quite a bit of work. I'll try to elaborate over the weekend.